# order array descending in c # with lambda

Tags: c#

I want order to object array by one of its variables "n_common" and this gives me error:

> you can´t convert Lambda expressions in the type array because is not
>   a type delegate.

```
cartesian_product.Sort((a, b) => -1 * a.n_common.CompareTo(b.n_common));
```

I want to order descending my "Pair" object that contains 3 variable "p", "q" and "n_common", it should be ordered by the "n_common", the cartesian_product is a array of Pair object.

I am not working with Linq just with Lambda expression or at least that is how I understand it anyway I put the linq in the header and the problem continues

Comment: No because I am not working with Linq just with Lambda expression or at least that is how I understand it anyway I put the linq in the header and the problem continues

Comment: What is the type of cartisian_product? What do you expect your lambda to do. I believe that Sort is expecting a delegate that takes an instance of the type the collection is collecting and return a value that can be sorted. Something like `people.Sort(p => p.Age)` would take a collection of persons (in a variable *people* and sort them by age. In your case, the delegate is specifying a function that takes two parameters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sort` is a static method, so it must be called from the class `Array` not an instance. Try this:

```
Array.Sort(cartesian_product, (a, b) => -1 * a.n_common.CompareTo(b.n_common));
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your class add `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Data.Entity;`.

Comment: No because I am not working with Linq just with Lambda expression or at least that is how I understand it anyway I put the linq in the header and the problem continues

Comment: The various extension methods that take a lambda expression (for example `Sort`) are defined in `System.Linq`. You may not think you are using LINQ, but you are.